# MSA account as Application Pool Identity automatically changed to ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: windows, iis

Yesterday I managed to set an MSA account as an Application Pool Identity successfully.
But somewhen during the time between yesterday and now, the identity changed back to the default `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

There could be 2 reasons that I think of, or, something else that I don't and please let me know:

1. Yesterday, I clicked on "Set Application Pool Defaults" because someone changed the defaults from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to something else. So I just changed the defaults back. So maybe after some time of doing that, the IIS changes everything back to `ApplicationPoolIdentity` - although it's weird, because I just checked now, and even if I change defaults again, it doesn't change the existing pools identities. Unless - it happens in a delay and that's what happened - somewhen during the time between yesterday and today.
   *Note however that my custom MSA account is under a separate Application Pool, not the Default one
2. I removed my MSA user from the server completely. It is not an admin or even a local user, because it is a domain name: `my-domain/my_msa_account$`. So maybe after a while IIS is doing some things in the background that require the Identity user to also be a local user or an admin, and if it doesn't find it, it changes to the default identity?

Or, something else caused the MSA identity to be changed to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`? I really need to know why it happened because I need to do this change on the production server as well